# MacOS finding classes at launchtime

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

Is there a way to determine which classes are present at launch time?

I have a Swift OS-X app that offers an API to add functionality. Not dynamically though, everything is fixed at launch time.

But is it possible to find out which classes are present at launch, and then from there to call a certain (inherited) static operation on these classes?

Absent this possibility I will have to create an initialisation routine that must be updated every time a new subclass is added. I would like to avoid this.

Clarification: I have a protocol call it MyProtocol. At launch of the App I would like to call an operation from MyProtocol on all classes that implement MyProtocol.

After examining the runtime manual I have gotten as far as:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include "Test.h"
#import <objc/objc-class.h>

void activateLaunchActions() {

    // Get a list of all classes
    int numClasses = 0, newNumClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);
    Class *classes = NULL;
    while (numClasses < newNumClasses) {
        numClasses = newNumClasses;
        Class newClasses[numClasses];
        classes = newClasses;
        newNumClasses = objc_getClassList(classes, numClasses);
    }

    // Get the protocol they have to confirm to
    Protocol *prot = objc_getProtocol("MyProtocol");

    // Get the selector to be called
    SEL sel = sel_registerName("launchAction");

    // Create the launchAction caller from objc_msgSend
    typedef void (*send_type)(Class, SEL);
    send_type callLauchAction = (send_type)objc_msgSend;

    // Call the registration for all classes that confirm to the protocol
    for (int i=0; i<numClasses; i++) {
        if (class_conformsToProtocol(classes[i], prot)) {
            callLauchAction(classes[i], sel);
        }
    }
}
```

The "prot" is always NULL. Hence the test later fails and the launchAction is never called.

I have read that protocol objects are not always present if they are not used by a class, however this protocol is used by several classes.

Any suggestions as how to fix this would be welcome.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Listing all classes matching a certain pattern and call a method on them? Can you give a concrete example? I'd suggest you give the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-88860) a read first

Comment: I added a clarification. Thanks for the pointer to the runtime reference, I am reading it now...

Comment: Seems promising, the "objc_getClassList" returns a list of classes, "class_conformsToProtocol" tells me if the class implements the protocol, all that is left is to invoke the proper operation. I will examine this tomorrow...